# reason of IllegalMonitorStateException if I use wait within sync block

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronization, wait

I try to understand java core synchronization.

I wrote code sample:

Program should write

> left 
>   right

10 times

```
package concurrency;

public class LeftRightWaitNotifyExample {
    final static String str = "1";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new LeftLegThread(str).start();
        new RightLegThread(str).start();
    }
}

class LeftLegThread extends Thread {
    String monitor;

    public LeftLegThread(String str) {
        monitor = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                System.out.println("Left ");
                wait();
            }
        }
    }
}

class RightLegThread extends Thread {
    String monitor;

    public RightLegThread(String str) {
        monitor = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Right ");
                notify();
                wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I get this output:

```
Left 
Right 
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at concurrency.LeftLegThread.makeStep(LeftRightWaitNotifyExample.java:35)
    at concurrency.LeftLegThread.run(LeftRightWaitNotifyExample.java:23)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notify(Native Method)
    at concurrency.RightLegThread.makeStep(LeftRightWaitNotifyExample.java:61)
    at concurrency.RightLegThread.run(LeftRightWaitNotifyExample.java:51)
```

Before I got this error when I used `wait` method  non within `synchronized` block. But here I use wait within `synchronized` block

What is the cause of the problem and how to fix it?

### update

I rewrite code according advice:

```
public class LeftRightWaitNotifyExample {
    final static String str = "1";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        new LeftLegThread(str).start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        new RightLegThread(str).start();
    }
}

class LeftLegThread extends Thread {
    String monitor;

    public LeftLegThread(String str) {
        monitor = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
                System.out.println("Left ");
                monitor.wait();
                monitor.notify();
            }
        }
    }
}

class RightLegThread extends Thread {
    String monitor;

    public RightLegThread(String str) {
        monitor = str;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Right ");
                monitor.notify();
                monitor.wait();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

current output:

```
Left 
Right 
Left 
Right 
Right
```

Why does `Right` outs 3 but `Left` only twice. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are synchronizing on `monitor`, so you should `wait()` on monitor, too:

```
monitor.wait();
```

Right now you are waiting on `this`, which is not the owner of the monitor because synchronization is on `monitor`.

Note that of course the `notify` should also be done on the `monitor` object, and that you might want to consider using `notify`/`notifyAll` in *both* threads. Otherwise it may happen that one thread starves waiting for a missing notification. Using a timeout (the overloaded version  of `wait`) might also be a good idea to catch corner cases.

Comment: really. amazing. But after replacing I see **Left 
Right 
Left ** and program is freezes

Answer (score 1):

The reason - `The current thread is not the owner of the object's monitor`.To call `wait()` method the current thread must own this object's monitor.
In your case you are obtaining monitor on `monitor` object instead current object(this object).

Comment: I have misunderstanding. I can use wait only on synchronized(this) ?

Comment: @gstackoverflow No you can use any object but the rule is `you have to call wait() method on object which is synchronized`.

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to lock monitor object.But it is locking thread object (LeftLegThread,RightLegThread).Actually it is not locked with synchronization.

monitor.wait(); will fix.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class LeftRightWaitNotifyExample {
    final static String str = "1";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        new LeftLegThread(str).start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        new RightLegThread(str).start();
    }
}

class LeftLegThread extends Thread {
    String monitor;

    public LeftLegThread(String str) {
        monitor = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Left ");
                monitor.wait();
                monitor.notify();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}

class RightLegThread extends Thread {
    String monitor;

    public RightLegThread(String str) {
        monitor = str;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            makeStep();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
    }

    private void makeStep() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (monitor) {
            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Right ");
                monitor.notify();
                monitor.wait();
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```